# Angular 5 sync provide of injection token

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

I'd like to know if there's a way to wait the provide of an `InjectionToken` until a `useFactory` of a previous provider is finished.

For example i'd like to set `MyInjectionToken` when the `APP_INITIALIZER` token has been assigned.

```
providers: [
HttpClient,
MyService
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: (...) => myService.asyncFunction(),
  deps: [EnvironmentService, LoggerService],
  multi: true
},
{
  provide: MyInjectionToken
  useFactory: myService.function()
}
```

Comment: See my answer. Instead of `APP_INITIALIZER`, I'd set a service as dependency that is initialized using `APP_INITIALIZER`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think my answer makes sense (deleted). I think you should use observables that notify when a service is done initializing. This way all dependencies can be immediately resolved but no other code that depends on a service being fully initialized uses it before it doesn't notify to be ready.

Comment: exactly, and I don't know another way except using the APP_INITIALIZER token

Comment: I have to set the value of an Injection Token (provide it in the AppModule), but I can only get its value when the useFactory of a APP_INITIALIZER is finished

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the answer you wrote me before works!

{
      provide: ProjectName,
      useFactory: myFactory,
      deps: [APP_INITIALIZER]
    },